# How can I get the article content from my json file through its slug(also present in json file) in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have links in my `index.vue` of my articles (in a Nuxt app). When an article is clicked the slug is added to the URL(this works fine). I don't know how I can get the specific article's content from the JSON file when clicked on the article link. More like I do not know how I can get the specific article's content in `pages/ArticleContent/_id.vue`.

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<h1> The Article Hub </h1>
    <div class="list_article">
        <div v-for="article in article_list" :key="article.title_slug">
            <nuxt-link :to="'/ArticleContent/' + article.title_slug">
                {{article.article_name}}
            </nuxt-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import example from '../assets/example_all_articles.json';

export default {
    data () {
    return {
        article_list: example.data.guides,
    }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My JSON file contains something like this:

```
article_name: Article A
article_id: 1
title_slug: article-a
article_content: This is content of article A

article_name: Article B
article_id: 2
title_slug: article-b
article_content: This is content of article B


article_name: Article C
article_id: 3
title_slug: article-c 
article_content: This is content of article C
```

and so on.

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this on the `_id.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="article">
      <h1>{{article.title_slug}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div v-else></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import articles_service from '../assets/example_all_articles.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      article_list: articles_service.data.guides,
      article: null
    }
  },
  asyncData({ params }) {
    return {
      id: params.id
    }
  },
  watch: {
    id: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(id) {
        if (id) {
          this.article = this.article_list.find(f => {
            return f.title_slug === this.id
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Make sure that `title_slug` are unique in the list.